# How to use forloop to compare elements of same array in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi Actually I am a beginner in Scala and spark. So this might be an easy one but I don't know how to approach this problem

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog","tiger","lion","cat","panther","eagle"))

val b = a.map(x.length,x)
```

and the desired output is

```
Array[(Int,String)]=Array((4,lion),(7,panther),(3,dogcat),(5,tigereagle))
```

This is what I tried

```
 val res = a.collect()
 for ( i <- 0 to (res.length - 2) ) {
   for ( j <- 1 to (res.length - 1 ) ) {
   if (res(i).length==res33(j).length && res(i) != res(j))println((res(i).concat(res(j))))
 }}
```

But not getting o/p in desired way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group by the length of the string and then map over the grouped result to transform the output the way you want.

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog", "tiger", "lion", "cat", "panther", "eagle"))

//group by length of the string and concatenate each string having same length
val b = a.groupBy(_.length).map(x => (x._1, x._2.mkString("")))

//print the output
b.foreach(print(_))

//output
//(3,dogcat)(4,lion)(7,panther)(5,tigereagle)
```

If you the result as an `Array[(Int, String)]` then use collect as,

```
val array: Array[(Int, String)] = b.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val list = List("dog","tiger","lion","cat","panther","eagle")
list: List[String] = List(dog, tiger, lion, cat, panther, eagle)

scala>val r = list.groupBy(_.length)collect{
  case e=> e._1 -> e._2.mkString("")
}
r: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(5 -> tigereagle, 4 -> lion, 7 -> panther, 3 -> dogcat)
scala> r.toArray
res3: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((5,tigereagle), (4,lion), (7,panther), (3,dogcat))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple use `groupBy`

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog","tiger","lion","cat","panther","eagle"))

a.groupBy(_.length).foreach(println)
```

This gives you `CompactBuffer` for each key having the same length as

```
(5,CompactBuffer(tiger, eagle))
(4,CompactBuffer(lion))
(3,CompactBuffer(dog, cat))
(7,CompactBuffer(panther))
```

Now you can the CompactBuffer as you require
now map through RDD and for each CompactBuffer `mkstring` function to create a single `string`

```
a.groupBy(_.length).map(x => (x._1, x._2.mkString("")))
```

This gives you

```
(4,lion)
(7,panther)
(3,dogcat)
(5,tigereagle)
```